# material-table How do I select a row changing the background color upon selection

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

Using the material-table library.
I would like to replicate the behavior shown in this example.

https://codesandbox.io/s/table-hover-colors-zw9nt

https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-table
https://material-table.com/#/
[image]

I was thinking of using onRowClick={}

The logic would be

onRowClick =>

1. set value in component state that renders clicked rows background to a different color
2. set all other rows to background to the original color

I can use conditional rendering based on a value held in state to change the background. Although this changes the background for all rows.

```
options={
   rowStyle:{backgroundColor: this.state.selected ? '#fff' : this.state.c}
}
```

[image]

My current working example is here
https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-haibt-2nefw

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You also need to pass the `selectedRowId` otherwise everything will be blue. Also, the `rowStyle` options accept a callback, which you could invoke like so:

```
rowStyle: rowData => ({
backgroundColor: this.state.selected && rowData.tableData.id === this.state.selectedRowId 
?   this.state.c
    : "#fff" 
})
```

Your `onRowClick` also needs some work (the select/unselect condition was not correct).
https://codesandbox.io/embed/select-one-row-160vm

Answer (score 2):

The package's [documentation](https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/styling) provides an example of how you can accomplish this with the `options` prop.

I forked your sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/select-one-row-cs32m).